# Can I publish an iOS app on Apple Store with some functions aren't available?

Tags: ios

I am developing an application and preparing to publish it on Apple Store. But there are some functions that I still haven't done yet. I decide to publish it to receive feedbacks for main functionalities, and will display an alert such as "This function isn't available yet" if user click on other functions. Can my app pass the review process?

Comment: It might depend on Apple Store.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. If something is not available why even show it? Say if you reach that functionality via a `UITableView` then delete that row and incorporate it once you have it.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to tell users that functionality is not available. Just remove it for now. Submitting application is not as difficult as you think. But it has to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not approve apps which are under development. But still if you want feedbacks for main functionalities you can submit build to iTunes and add internal tester/external tester for testing purpose so you can test via TestFlight app.
for reference read below guidelines from apple(read 2.9 section which is related to question.)

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality